# how to change button image in tableview when that button clicked

Tags: iphone

i need to place a check box in UItableview.

For that i place a box with out check image is place on button.

my code is,

```
UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 customButton.frame=CGRectMake(100, 10, 100, 100);
 [customButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [cell.contentView addSubview:customButton];
```

Now i need to change button image when button clicked.

where can i done this.

and how can i impalement  this.

can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//add this line
[customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//then
-(void) buttonClicked:(id) sender
{
   UIButton * button = (UIButton*) sender;
   [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this line of code

```
 [customButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected2.png"] forState:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

before

```
 [cell.contentView addSubview:customButton];
```

and you ca select different images for different events and states